# Feature selection methods when input data is continuous but target variable is categorical

Tags: time-series, feature-selection, binary

I plan on extracting features from a univariate time series, and use a feature selection method to select relevant features to predict a binary target variable via logistic regression. But, I have 2 major doubts:

1. How do I avoid collinearity when selecting features, given these time series-extracted features come from the same signal?
2. What’s the best feature selection method to implement, in this scenario?